# How to find which th child has the particular class for a table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find which th child has the class 'nosort' for the table with 'normal-sort-table' class using jquery ? I want to alert column number of th with 'nosort' class.

```
<table class="normal-sort-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th class="nosort">Username</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>mark246</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    if ( $('.normal-sort-table tr th').hasClass( "nosort" ) ) {alert( 'column-number-with-nosort-class-alert-here' )}


})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jq [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method:

```
$('.normal-sort-table tr th.nosort').index()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($("th").index($(".nosort")));
```

Comment: Could you also explain your answer?

Comment: Sure, but it is also helpful if you add the relevant parts of that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exact column number then you have write

```
alert($('th.nosort').index()+1);
```

becuase index starting from zero.

```
alert($('th.nosort').index());
```

```js
alert($('th.nosort').index()+1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="normal-sort-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th class="nosort">Username</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>mark246</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```